# Error "isDataSchedulerEnabled():false" in logcat

Tags: java, android, logging, error-handling, openweathermap

So I'm trying to fetch data from OpenWeatherMap, and I keep seeing the "isDataSchedulerEnabled():false" message in my logcat under the "DataScheduler" tag. Is this something I should be concerned about? I can't find anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error.
With me the problem was that the wifi was not working.
After i turned the wifi off and used data, my app started to work again.

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and my problem was passing wrong parameters to method.
when I corrected parameters my problem solved.

(I pass Illegal character '/' to method. I just replace It with '-')

Answer (score -2):

i believe its something like when ur app need internet service or something the app checks the state of the DataScheduler which is the internet connection but not with wifi....but with Data. I get the same error but my app is working because i have wifi when using it....however android mention that my data is not enable.